# Function to create/add another select (dropdown) box

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, addition

I need to find a away to insert/add a `<select>` (dropdown) box on click of a button. I want each click of the button to keep adding a new `<select>`.

Tested out some javascript/jquery functions and as I don't have much background in it, I'm having no luck!

**Edit:**
Sorry just kinda answered my own question with help from other questions to anyone wandering just view source code on this.

http://jsbin.com/ufuxuq/

that was pretty much what I wanted, but had to implement some php within the list so I had extra trouble with that, but it's all good now.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow - have a good read of the FAQS - you will find that people are more inclined to assist if you show some effort in your questions - so ... What have you tried so far ? can you post some examples

Comment: Can you give us some demo code that you're using? If you provide the base HTML, I'll bet we'll be able to scratch something together. Better to use your HTML than ours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry just kinda answered my own question with help from other questions to anyone wandering just view source code on this.

http://jsbin.com/ufuxuq/

that was pretty much what I wanted, but had to implement some php within the list so I had extra trouble with that, but it's all good now.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `<select>` element (or any other element) with `$("<select/>");`
The `append` function can be used to append html into an item.

Combining them yields:

```
$("#buttonToAddDD").click(function () {
    var newDD = $("<select/>");
    $(newDD).append("<option>New Option 1</option>");
    $(newDD).append("<option>New Option 2</option>");
    $("#whereYouWantToAddNewDD").append(newDD);
});

<div id="whereYouWantToAddNewDD"></div>
<input type="button" id="buttonToAddDD" value="Add DD" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically creating/removing a html code is easy with JQuery as explained above by Adam. However keep caution to provide users with facility to remove them as well.
Best way would be adding a id to the select box and provide a span/div with a close 'X' on clicking which either it could be removed completely

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
{
     $("#close").click({function(){

     $("#selectid").remove(); // to remove the select
     $("#selectid").hide(); //this would hide it but when submitted, the default/selected option shall still be submitted
     $("#close").remove();
     }):
});
```